# how to make eclipse run 2 diferent programs at the same time?

Tags: java, eclipse, server, console, client

I want to run a program which has a server and a client.

I want to run both of the server prog. and client prog. through eclipse

*the problem*: if I open 2 or 3 consoles in eclipse - they show me the same output!

I mean running 1 program, say the server, on 1 console, automatically writes the program output on the other server as well. I can't figure out how to run server on 1 console and the client on the other :-(

eclipse version is the one from june-2019.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: I do not know how. pretty new here in stackoverflow.. My apologies

Comment: you can make two different projects in eclipse and run them. You can then select console window for each running project.

Answer (score 1):

***Pin*** the console ([image]) and then choose the running application from which you want to see the output via the ***Display Selected Console*** button drop-down ([image]).

[Watch it here in my video](https://youtu.be/Y0-cO9wZj6w?t=74).